# Laravel 9 using AND or OR in combination which fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I want to write below queries but it doesn't produce the result that I want.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'DATA' AND ( COLUMN2 LIKE 'K%' OR COLUMN3 LIKE 'K%' OR COLUMN4 = 'ABC@GMAIL.COM')
```

I want above queries eloquent in Laravel 9, I have written as below but still doesn't produce the same result.

```
DB::table('table1')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
$query->where('column2', 'LIKE', $request -> data)
-> orWhere('column3', 'LIKE', $request -> data ) 
 -> orWhere('column4', '=', $request -> data ) ;
})->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the first `where` about `COLUMN1` isn't?

Currently, it produces:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (column2 LIKE 'a' OR column3 LIKE 'b' OR column4 = 'c')
```

Update your code to include the first `where`:

```php
DB::table('table1')
    ->where('column1', 'DATA')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('column2', 'LIKE', $request->data)
          ->orWhere('column3', 'LIKE', $request->data ) 
          ->orWhere('column4', '=', $request->data ) ;
    }
)->get();
```

And now, it should work as expected (at least, it will produce the query you are expecting).

Comment: Thanks, there was a missing that I had used orWhere instead of where of column1.